# Images are getting saved 10 times when I press capture once camera 2 onImageAvailable

Tags: android, android-camera2

```
private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener
            = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {

        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
            Image img = reader.acquireNextImage();
            ByteBuffer buffer = img.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];

            buffer.get(bytes);
            img.close();

            mBackgroundHandler.post(new ImageSaver(bytes, mFile));
        }




    };
```

Images are getting saved 10 times when I press capture once , i am stuck here

Comment: Why not debug your code and check why your saving code getting executes 10 times ?

Comment: @ADM I think this is because of `ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {`  , any idea how to remove listener after I capture it once , then reattach when I press capture again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 case STATE_WAITING_LOCK: {
                        Integer afState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE);
                        if (afState == null) {
                            mState = STATE_PICTURE_TAKEN;
                            captureStillPicture();
                        }
```

notice mState = STATE_PICTURE_TAKEN , this solved my problem